# WebAPI get request parameters being UrlDecoded at the controller

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, urlencode

I have an issue where I'm issuing a `GET` to a WebAPI controller, essentially:

```
$.getJSON('/api/feefo/getproductfeedback?id='+ encodeURIComponent(skuNum))
```

I'm using `encodeURIComponent` to url encode the `skuNum` parameter, viewing a request in dev tools I get the expected result for a `skuNum` that needs to be encoded:

[image]

The `skuNum` has gone from `1000EF+` to `1000EF%2B` as expected.

However, when I view the `id` parameter in the WebAPI controller, it's coming through un-encoded:

[image]

It's as though the client side url encoding is being undone somehow, can anyone explain what's going on here? Obviously I can work around this by just doing the encoding in the controller, but I'd like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: That is by design. The API framework will decode the URL encoded parameters by default. the encoding should only be used for transporting the data. once on server developer shouldn't have to deal with having to decode it (cross cutting concern). Use the value as intended.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks, makes sense I guess. Feel free to add this as an answer, it might help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is by design. The API framework will decode the URL encoded parameters by default. the encoding should only be used for transporting the data. once on server developer shouldn't have to deal with having to decode it (cross cutting concern). Use the value as intended.